# How to change file extension with Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that will take a file, say `my_test_file.log` and make a new file called `my_test_file.mdn`. I'd like to be able to use this program by typing `python renameprogram.py my_test_file.log` into the command line. The original file will always end in `.log`.

Comment: In addition to the above link, take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv and https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename

Answer (score 2):

```
from shutil import copyfile
from glob import glob
map(lambda x:copyfile(x,x[:-3]+"mdn"),glob("*.log"))
```

or perhaps more simply

```
...
import sys
copyfile(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[1][:-3]+"mdn")
```

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can create a Python program that will accomplish this, but there are shell level commands that already do this.

For Linux/Unix:

```
mv my_test_file.log my_test_file.mdn
```

For Windows (see [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490987.aspx) link):

```
rename my_test_file.log my_test_file.mdn
```

Comment: I believe you could even do `mv *.log *.mdn` (+1)

Comment: If you want to rename all files in the current directory, yes.

Comment: I know I can do this with unix, but the reason I'd like to do it in python is because I need to get a bunch of other data from the original file and put it into the new file in a different format I'd like to do this all with one program if possible, but that might be beyond my skills at the moment haha. This is just the first step.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: No, that wouldn't be the correct syntax. The `*.mdn` wouldn't expand to what you want it to expand to, and `mv` would complain about the target not being a directory.